# How to have batch "mimic" a key press (for macros and the like)

Tags: batch-file

Is there anyway to have batch "mimic" a key press, for example, you could have the batch file running, you could have it "type" a letter in an open ms word file every x amount of seconds, or minimize a program after a set time (by use of alt+tab)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with pure native batch. There are tools that can be installed to do this. [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) is a popular free tool that is designed to do what you want

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).  I consider it a "must-have" for the power user's toolkit.